# The size of a set with minimum interpoint distance in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a metric space, $(X,d)$ with finite doubling dimension $ddim(X)$ (Namely, for every $r>0$, every ball of radius $r$ can be covered by $2^{ddim(X)}$ balls of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ ), and a set $A\subseteq X$.

We want to bound the size of $A$, and we know that for each $x,y\in A$ s.t. $x\neq y$ we have 
$d(x,y)\geq \alpha$, and $diam(X)=\beta$.
We have the following claim:

$|A| \leq  {\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil}^{ddim(X)+1}$

I tired to find a proof for this claim, but I can only show that

$|A| \leq (2\cdot{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil})^{ddim(X)}$

Here is my proof:

We need at most $(2^{ddim(X)})^i$ balls of radius $\frac{\beta}{2^{i}}$ to cover $A$ .
Hence, we need at most $(2^{ddim(X)})^{{\lceil}log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil}}$ balls of radius $\alpha$ to cover $A$ .

Now, $(2^{ddim(X)})^{{\lceil}log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil}} \leq$
$(2^{ddim(X)})^{(log{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil}+1)} = $
$(2^{(log{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil}+1))^{ddim(X)}}$ = 
$(2\cdot{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil})^{ddim(X)}$

Now, since $(2\cdot{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil})^{ddim(X)}$ balls of radius $\alpha$ covers $A$, and the minimum interpoint distance in $A$ is at least $\alpha$, then $A$ contains at most $(2\cdot{\lceil}\frac{\beta}{\alpha}{\rceil})^{ddim(X)}$

How can I get a tighter bound? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, thanks. the size means the cardinality